# Fatal error - Assign value to array in for loop

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a simple **TwitterTweet** struct:

```
struct TwitterTweet {
    let userName: String
    let userDescription: String
    let userFollowersCount: Int
    let userProfileImage: String
    let tweetText: String
    let tweetRetweetCount: Int
    let tweetFavouriteCount: Int
}
```

and an array of the TwitterTweet struct:

```
//var twitterTweets: [TwitterTweet]?
var twitterTweets = [TwitterTweet]()
```

I retrieve and parse JSON data into an array of NSDictionary.
In the for-loop, I create a new TwitterTweet, but when I try and add it to the array at index i, i get the error:

**fatal error: Array index out of range**

```
if let data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: nil, error: &err) as? [NSDictionary] {
    if data.count != 0 {
        for var i = 0; i < data.count; i++ {
            if let
            tt = data[i]["text"] as? String,
            rc = data[i]["retweet_count"] as? Int,
            tc = data[i]["favorite_count"] as? Int {
                if let ud = data[i]["user"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let
                    un = ud["name"] as? String,
                    dc = ud["description"] as? String,
                    fc = ud["followers_count"] as? Int,
                    pi = ud["profile_image_url"] as? String {

                        let tweet = TwitterTweet(userName: un, userDescription: dc, userFollowersCount: fc, userProfileImage: pi, tweetText: tt, tweetRetweetCount: rc, tweetFavoriteCount: tc

                        self.twitterTweets[i] = tweet                              
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        println("no data")
        println("error: \(error)")
    }
```

I am not sure how to assign the array with size of **data.count**.
I have tried adding the following code before the for-loop

```
twitterTweets = [TwitterTweet](count: data.count, repeatedValue: nil)
```

But this does not work for me. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated, as I have already spent hours trying to figure out a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
twitterTweets += [tweet]
```

or

```
twitterTweets.append(tweet)
```

or

```
twitterTweets.splice([tweet], atIndex: i)
```

Comment: No problem! Sometimes just writing out the question helps… sometimes you have to wait for someone to answer :)